# Does a rational number to the n-th power exists between a and b integers ? If yes, how to find one easily?

Tags: rational-numbers

Let $a,b,n\in\mathbb N^*$, $a<b$,

Does a rational $p/q$ such that $p,q\in\mathbb N$ and $a<p^n/q^n<b$ exist ?

If that's the case, Is there a way to find one ?

I know that $\mathbb {\bar Q} = \mathbb R$ ($\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$).

If we let $\mathbb Q_n = \{p^n/q^n|p\in\mathbb Z\,,q\in\mathbb N^*\}$, I would say that $\forall n\in\mathbb N, \mathbb {\bar Q_{2n+1}} = \mathbb R$ and $\mathbb {\bar Q_{2n+2}} = \mathbb R^+$.

But I am not sure how to prove it. What would you do ?

Thank you !

Edit : When I say "to find one",  it is by using a formula which should use $a$ and $b$

Comment: For the first part, take nth roots

Comment: Take any rational between $\sqrt[n]{a}$ and $\sqrt[n]{b}$

Comment: Oh yes ! I see what you mean if I choose $a^{1/n}$ and $b^{1/n}$ because $\mathbb {\bar Q} = \mathbb R$  we know that there is a $p/q$ such that $a^{1/n}<p/q<b^{1/n}$ !

Answer (score 3):

The map $x \to x^n$ is a homeomorphism of the positive real line. Since the rationals are dense, so is the set of their $n$th powers, so there will be many such in any interval.

How to "find one" depends on the tools you allow.